# Why throwing ThreadAbortException doesn't kill the process?

Tags: c#, .net, exception

We all know that in c# if any exception is thrown, it terminates or kill the process immediately,
which is not the case for `ThreadAbortException`.Why there is a special behaviour for this exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the main thread can choose to cancel the exception and/or wait for the thread to finish and then continue processing.

> When a call is made to the Abort method to destroy a thread, the
>   common language runtime throws a ThreadAbortException.
>   ThreadAbortException is a special exception that can be caught, but it
>   will automatically be raised again at the end of the catch block. When
>   this exception is raised, the runtime executes all the finally blocks
>   before ending the thread. Because the thread can do an unbounded
>   computation in the finally blocks or call Thread.ResetAbort to cancel
>   the abort, there is no guarantee that the thread will ever end. If you
>   want to wait until the aborted thread has ended, you can call the
>   Thread.Join method. Join is a blocking call that does not return until
>   the thread actually stops executing.

See [ThreadAbortException Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadabortexception.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

This is because ThreadAbortException is supposed to terminate only thread on which it was thrown. But there could be another threads still running, so process won't exit until all foreground threads exit.